# How to measure distance between apple watch and iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

I know that core bluetooth is not available in watchOS2 so there is no way to read RSSI. But app like lookout released watch app that has a distance indicator. How did they do that? Any thought?

Comment: Did you solve? I'm wondering the same

Comment: @StefanoGiacone Until today, there is no way to access bluetooth info on apple watch.

Answer (score 0):

Using interactive messing pass mobile location to apple watch and calculate distance to shown on watch

Refer below apple link for communicating with the counterpart app

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession

Comment: Now,  bluetooth is available in watchOS4 so there is way to read RSSI